# Can't show Debug output on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: debugging, azure, visual-studio-2012, azure-storage, azure-diagnostics

I tried to configure the storage for my debugging data in Azure Storage by following the instructions in this page [(source)](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics/). After doing this the outputs from Diagnostics like Debug.WriteLine stopped appearing on the Debug output of Visual Studio which I didn't intend to happen.

After a while it was decided it wasn't necessary to store the debug data in the end, so I deleted the diagnostics.wadcfg file and removed the diagnostics configuration from the Web.config file of my role and from both ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg and ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg files, hoping that would restore the output to Visual Studio . It didn't.

How can I restore fully the Debug output to be displayed on Visual Studio console once again? It's really hard to work without these outputs of information.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Visual Studio > Tools> Options > Debugging > Output Window > And check the options there for Output types.

Comment: all the General Output Settings are on, on the WPF Trace Settings all are off, except for Data Binding which is in Warning. 
On General Output Settings there's an setting called All debug output which is On

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are runnning the project un Debug mode and not in Release mode.

Answer (score 0):

In window--->Reset window layout